How to store large dataset into Ethereum chain?
I am building AI and Blockchain based healthcare application.
The issue is how to store large patient data into Ethereum chain. As you know, Ethereum network is safe, but it is cost for storing large dataset.
I am also planning to use decentralized storages like Filecoin.
Here are some references.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gyw7-22mOZPsA5PvRCcqDTLIngw6390d/view?usp=sharing
https://bitbucket.org/blocktechai/nearest-doctor/src/main/

Your approach of using Filecoin is a good one. You could upload the data to Filecoin or simply IPFS. When you do this, you would get the uri for this upload. You can access or refer this uri whenever you want. You can also, using ERC721 or ERC1155 for associating the patients uri with the appropriate patient.
